# Zoom function on SVG with smartGWT

Tags: java, gwt, svg, smartgwt

Our task is to build a zoom function like the Google Maps zoom function on a existing SVG map.

We use GWT 2.4 to compile our java code to Javascript. Unfortunately, we found no method to zoom on our map.

Is there any function we didn't found?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Had you looked at  :

```
http://www.vectomatic.org/gwt/vectomatic2/vectomatic2.html
https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/lib-gwt-svg/YbNIfYBRmSg
```

Hoping it could help.

Comment: Hi ...!
Thank you for the links.
We want to use the SVGZoomHandler like Gabriel (from the google groups). Lukas said that there aren't so much informations or comments on the Internet about that. And this is our problem. 
We can't find any examples ... and it seems like nobody want to deal with SVGZoomHandler.